# MVC Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: model-view-controller, view

This error is driving me crazy. i am trying to simply print a property in the view but keep getting 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object .

If i hoover over this property i can clearly see there is a value

```
  <div id="tab1" class="lt_content">

     @Model.NewRentals.Description

 </div>
```

This is the controller :

```
SearchVM searchvm = null;

            if (propertyType == "Rentals")
            {

                searchvm = new SearchVM
                {
                    FeatureRentals = from c in context.Rentals
                          orderby c.Amount ascending 
                                where c.FeatureProperty ==true && c.Active==true
                                select c,

                    Rentals = from c in context.Rentals
                              where c.RentalID == propertyID
                    select c,

                    Agents = from c in context.Agents
                             select c,

                    PropertyAgent = GetRentalAgentDetails(propertyID),

                    NewRentals = GetCurrentRental(propertyID),

                };
```

and the method GetCurrentRental

```
public Rental GetCurrentRental(int id)
        {
            Rental rental = context.FindRentalByID(id);

            return rental;
        }
```

Comment: Could you show the controller action that is rendering this view? There are 2 possible reasons why you could get this error: `Model` is null or `Model.NewRentals` is null. So make sure that this is not the case before trying to access the `Description` property.

Comment: This is not the case, i hoover my mouse over that property in the view and can see value against @Model.NewRentals.Description

Comment: If you can see a value then you wouldn't get a NRE. But just to be sure, what does the following show at runtime: `@((Model == null)).ToString()`. How about this: `@((Model.NewRentals == null)).ToString()`?

Comment: its not null, the model or the property

Comment: Then you cannot possible get a NRE on this line: `@Model.NewRentals.Description`. It's probably somewhere else.

Comment: thats the thing, its got a value but not sure why i am getting that error, maybe i need to convert it to string or something